# Redirect in the browser without leaving the page

Tags: javascript, http, redirect, browser, http-redirect

The way authentication works in our webapp is that after 2 mins of user idle time it redirect the next HTTP request to the auth server to refresh access token which is then placed in a cookie which is used to authenticate subsequent HTTP requests. So, if the user is idle longer than 2 mins and then tries to submit a form, the redirect to auth server loses form data and sends the user back to the empty form.

We have no control over the auth server and would like to come up with a mechanism that would periodically perform a background redirect to auth server without leaving the current page. One option is to use an embedded iframe, but this makes it nontrivial setting the cookie on the main page after the redirect. Is it possible or appropriate to use HTML5 web workers for that? Any other solutions?

Thanks

Comment: You should be able to do it with AJAX, I think.

Comment: Why would you have to set the cookie? The cookie will be updated for the current page, that page does not magically still have the old cookie.

Comment: @Barmar Unfortunately auth server is on a different domain and doesn't set headers required for allowing CORS during AJAX

Comment: @epascarello Because the backend of our webapp verifies the access token set in the cookie and if it's invalid rejects HTTP request.

Comment: The browser will send up the new cookie with the next request...Try it out. Only reason it would fail is if the token sat in an hidden input field on the current page.

Comment: @epascarello You didn't propose a solution. I know how cookies work. The question was about background refresh options besides embedded iframe.